# sql Column 1 and Column 2 contain same value then condition A else B

Tags: sql, join, case

This is my query, but it show the result is not my expected.

```
SELECT  
a.PROJECT_NO, 
CASE WHEN a.PROJECT_NO = b.PROJECT_NO THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS CONDITION 
FROM PROJECT a
LEFT OUTER JOIN WORKSHEET b ON (b.PROJECT_NO = a.PROJECT_NO)

Table a                 Table b
Project_No              Project_No
1111                    1111  
2222                    3333 
3333                    
4444
```

The correct result should be

```
Project_No      Condition           
1111             True                
2222             FALSE               
3333             TRUE                
4444             FALSE
```

My query result,all condition status show true

```
Project_No      Condition
1111             TRUE 
2222             TRUE 
3333             TRUE
4444             TRUE
```

Anyone can help me to fix it.Thanks

Comment: Your query should be returning the results you want.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  Actually, your query has unbalanced parentheses, so it would not return anything other than an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.PROJECT_NO = b.PROJECT_NO` always returns `null` when `b.PROJECT_NO = null` and the first`WHEN` in `CASE` is choosen which returns `TRUE`, otherwise, when `b.PROJECT_NO` is not `NULL` `TRUE` is returned too due to correct equality result. So the easiest approach is to use `IS NULL` condition to the `t2.Project` column :

```
SELECT a.PROJECT_NO
     , (CASE WHEN b.PROJECT_NO IS NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS CONDITION 
FROM PROJECT a LEFT OUTER JOIN WORKSHEET b ON b.PROJECT_NO = a.PROJECT_NO
```

Comment: The parenthesis in the `CASE` line are unbalanced, please check them

Answer (score 1):

wrap it with `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN a.PROJECT_NO = b.PROJECT_NO THEN 'TRUE' END, 'FALSE')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **[ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)**

Try this

```
SELECT  
a.PROJECT_NO, 
CASE WHEN (ISNULL(a.PROJECT_NO,0) = IsNULL(b.PROJECT_NO,1) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS CONDITION 
FROM PROJECT a
LEFT OUTER JOIN WORKSHEET b ON (b.PROJECT_NO = a.PROJECT_NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it and you won't need the join anymore

SELECT
a.PROJECT_NO,

CASE WHEN a.PROJECT_NO IN (SELECT PROJECT_NO FROM WORKSHEET) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS CONDITION

FROM PROJECT a

Answer (score 0):

**Another way :)**

```
SELECT a.PROJECT_NO, 
       COALESCE (CONDITION,'FALSE') AS CONDITION FROM 
PROJECT a
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 'TRUE' AS CONDITION  
    FROM WORKSHEET
    WHERE PROJECT_NO =  a.PROJECT_NO
) AS Sub
```

Thanks,
[barua.me](http://barua.me)